# How to create hibernate hbm.xml considering the super class?

Tags: hibernate

I have my entity like this

```
public class Automobile{
  private int noOfTyre;
  }

  // car extending Automobile

 public class Car extends Automobile{
  private String engine; 
  private String id;
  }

 public class Bus extends Automobile{
  private String engine; 
  private String id;
  }
```

I want to create an `hbm.xml` for my Car so that I can do db operations. My `Car.hbm.xml` looks like this

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="car"
        table="car">
        <id name="id" type="string" column="id">
            <!-- <generator class="native"/> -->
        </id>
        <property name="engine" type="string" />
        <property name="noOfTyre" type="int" />  // attribute of Automobile
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The above contains the attributes of Car and Automobile for my table to look like this

[image: table Car]

***Is there any way to decouple the attributes of the super class Automobile so that I can reuse the same in every hbm.xml of child classes?***